# Any way to duplicate elements to prevent repetitive code in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry this is probably a silly question, but I'm writing out a restaurant menu page, and want to create some way to display multiple food items/descriptions in a grid-like (3x5) pattern onto the page without manually coding out 15 nearly identical divs for each one.

Any help or solution would be amazing!

```
<div class="menu-column-wrapper">
            <div class="menu-column">
                <div class="menu-item">
                    <div class="item-header">
                        <h3>Item</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-description">
                        <p>Description</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is how I currently have this menu section set up, with 3 separate "menu-column" divs, each containing 5 nested "menu-item" divs.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you looking for this to done with python (flask/django) or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that with the code below.

Basically, it's solved in javascript using template literals.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="menu-column-wrapper" />
 </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const menuItem = `
    <div class="menu-item">
    <div class="item-header">
      <h3>Item</h3>
     </div>
    <div class="item-description">
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
  const menuColumn = `
    <div class="menu-column">
      ${menuItem}
      ${menuItem} 
      ${menuItem} 
      ${menuItem} 
      ${menuItem} 
    </div>
    `
  const menuColumnWrapper = document.querySelector('.menu-column-wrapper');
  menuColumnWrapper.innerHTML = `
    ${menuColumn}
    ${menuColumn}
    ${menuColumn}
  `
});
```

Comment: How does this implement an actual solution to the OP's needs? The here code is hard-wired to _static_ data as defined in the ```menuItem``` constant. Presuming that he _actually_ wants each and every instance of the ```DIV``` to represent _disparate_ food items from the menu, how is this an actual solution to his problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an html engine like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or [ejs](https://ejs.co/) etc...
With [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) your html code will lock something like :

```
<div class="menu-column-wrapper">
   {{#each food}}
    <div class="menu-column">
         <div class="menu-item">
              <div class="item-header">
                   <h3>{{this.Item}}</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="item-description">
                 <p>{{this.Description}}</p>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

with js array :

```
food [
   {Item: 'item1', Description: 'desc1'},
   {Item: 'item2', Description: 'desc2'},
   {Item: 'item3', Description: 'desc3'}
]
```

Comment: Why would you recommend wasting the time / effort  / overhead of incorporating an external library for such an easy/basic operation?

Comment: I see it as saving time / effort .

Comment: LoL -- in my experience, rarely does finding, downloading, installing, implementing and maintaining _entire_ 3rd party libraries _just_ to avoid writing _maybe_ 100 lines of wholly independent native JS code equal 'saving time / effort' 

Answer (score 1):

You can use grid or flex-box. Here's a grid example.

```css
.menu-column-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
  width: min-content;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px grey solid;
}
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px grey solid;
}
h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
  width: 75px;
  height:auto;
}
p {
  font-size: 9pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-column-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Chicken Pot Pie</h3>
    <img src="https://dinnerthendessert.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Chicken-Pot-Pie-3.jpg" alt="pie"/>
    <p>This is a description of some food. It has chicken and carrots.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Chicken Curry</h3>
    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/190509-coconut-chicken-curry-157-1558039780.jpg?crop=0.668xw:1.00xh;0.116xw,0&resize=480:*" alt="curry"/>
    <p>This is a spicy dish served over rice. Includes peppers and carrots.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <h3>Item</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this acomodate the part where he says,  _"without manually coding out 15 nearly identical divs for each one"_ ?? I don't see how the CSS information is relevant to the actual question being asked?

Comment: OP is going to have to write out the Item and Description regardless of how he creates the elements. I removed the extra `divs` he had and simplified the menu. Sure he can go the js route and write up a function and still have to type in all the descriptions or he can do it in the html. Whatever makes more sense to them is what they’ll do.

Comment: Oh and as for the css he has it tagged for a reason I assume. Maybe he’s looking for option.

Comment: His sample code already included CSS class names, so I presumed that they're already defined. His _question_ was how to build the numerous structurally identical ```DIV``` containers _without_ manually coding them, and your HTML 'solution' _literally_ hand-codes ~14 structurally identical div's with purely static content..? 

Comment: That’s great and all but options are nice to have. Maybe he didn’t think about the fact he would be writing a 50 line function to create 20 `<p>` tags and then he still has to type in all of the description info. Then again maybe he did and that’s exactly what he wants to do. Guess what he’ll do if he doesn’t like my answer? He’ll move on to the next and life will go on.

Answer (score -2):

The thin framework below should dynamically create a skeleton page and populate it with the specified information as you're requesting. I don't know the name of your CSS file, so you'll obviously have to include that, but this should show you how to dynamically construct a page containing some unknown number of approximately-identical internal structures on the fly:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zk3th8j9/1/

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script language='javascript'>
        var menu = [
            [ "item0", "desc0" ], [ "item1", "desc1" ], [ "item2", "desc2" ], // row 1
            [ "item3", "desc3" ], [ "item4", "desc4" ], [ "item5", "desc5" ], // row 2
            [ "item6", "desc6" ], [ "item7", "desc7" ], [ "item8", "desc8" ], // row 3
            [ "item9", "desc9" ], [ "itemA", "descA" ], [ "itemB", "descB" ], // row 4
            [ "itemC", "descC" ], [ "itemD", "descD" ], [ "itemE", "descE" ], // row 5
        ];

        function CreateBasicDiv( className )
        {
            var div = document.createElement( "div" );
    
            div.className = className;
            // optional: assign any other DIV parameters you need/want...
    
            return div;
        }

        function CreateItemDiv( item, desc )
        {
            var div = [], classes = [ "menu-column-wrapper", "menu-column", "menu-item", "item-header", "item-descripton" ];

            // iteratively create a series of <DIV> elements with proper classNames
            for( var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ )
                div[ i ] = CreateBasicDiv( classes[ i ] );

            // consider putting the 'h3' styling into the CSS, or the 'item' string itself
            div[ 3 ].innerHTML = "<h3>" + item + "</h3>";

            // likewise, the <p>aragraphing should probably be done within the 'desc' string...
            div[ 4 ].innerHTML = "<p>" + desc + "</p>"

            div[ 2 ].appendChild( div[ 3 ] );
            div[ 2 ].appendChild( div[ 4 ] );

            // 'nest' the div's...
            for (var i = 2; i > 0; )
               div[ i-1 ].appendChild( div[ i-- ] );

            return div[ 0 ];
        }

        function CreateMenu()
        {
            var table = document.createElement( "table" ), 
                colCount = 3, i = 0, width = Math.round( 90 / colCount );

            // Override class definitions for these settings:
            table.style = "position:relative;width:90%;left:5%;top:50px;table-layout:fixed;";

            while ( i < menu.Length )
            {
               var tr = document.createElement( "tr" );
               do {
                  var td = document.createElement( "td" );
                  td.style.width = width + "%"; // <-- enforce cell width
                  td.appendChild( CreateItemDiv( menu[ i ][0], menu[ i ][1] ) );
                  tr.appendChild( td );
               } while ( (++i < menu.length) && (i % colCount > 0) )
               table.appendChild( tr );
            }
            document.body.appendChild( table );
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='CreateMenu();'></body>
</html>
```